# Why does Seaborn lineplot "size" argument end up as legend artist?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, seaborn

In a simple lineplot from Seaborn sample data, adding a "size" argument to control linewidth automatically adds an artist/handle to the legend generated from the "label" argument.

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('geyser')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.lineplot(
    x=df.waiting,
    y=df.duration,
    label='Label',
    size=3,
    ax=ax
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

What is the reason for this behavior, and what can be done to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `linewidth` parameter to set the width of the line. The size parameter does something else. Check out the examples in the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) to see how to use it. The image below gives a good impression, and also makes it clear why the parameter results in a legend entry.

[image]

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a `linewidth` parameter in the [doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)?

Comment: @KristianCanler That's included in the "Other keyword arguments are passed down to matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot().", since seaborn is built on top of matplotlib and the seaborn lineplot is just a matplotlib plot with extra features.

Answer (score 1):

The size is used to group, and will have different size lines based on a category.

For example you can have different size based on the `kind` column:

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('geyser')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.lineplot(
    x=df.waiting,
    y=df.duration,
    label='Label',
    size = df['kind'],
    ax=ax
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Not sure what it's doing as a number though. You use `linewidth` to set the line size though:

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('geyser')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.lineplot(
    x=df.waiting,
    y=df.duration,
    label='Label',
    linewidth = 3,
    ax=ax
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a `linewidth` parameter in the [doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)? The parameter seems to work when I call it but I don't see it in the doc

Comment: It's in the `Other keyword arguments are passed down to matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot()` [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot)